# Kafka consumer.poll call not returning kafka ConsumerRecords

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new to the kafka technology..I'm working on POC where I need to send `ProducerRecord<String, Paymnt>` to Kafka Topic where Paymnt is my POJO..I was able to publish record & I could see messages being delivered to Kafka topic..

```
D:\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\bin\windows>kafka-run-class.bat kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test --time -1
test:2:0
test:1:0
test:0:4
```

However on Consumer side I'm not able to retrieve same record..When I debug the consumer code,I see thread call blocking on `consumer.poll()`

Consumer class

```
public class Consumer {



public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    KafkaConsumer<String, Paymnt> consumer = null;
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "com.org.kafkaPro.PaymentDeSerializer");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
    try {
        consumer =new KafkaConsumer<String, Paymnt>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));
            while(true){

            ConsumerRecords<String, Paymnt> records = consumer.poll(200);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String,Paymnt> record : records)
            {
                System.out.println(record.value().toString());
            }

            consumer.commitAsync();
            }

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        consumer.commitSync();
        consumer.close();
    }
}
}
```

PaymentDeserliazer class

```
 package com.org.kafkaPro;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInput;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

    public class PaymentDeSerializer implements Deserializer<Paymnt> {

        public PaymentDeSerializer(){

        }

        public void close() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public Paymnt deserialize(String arg0, byte[] arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(arg1);
            ObjectInputStream in = null;
            Paymnt h2 = null;
            try {
                in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                 h2 = (Paymnt) in.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return h2;
        }

}
```

Paymnt class

```
public class Paymnt  {

//fields,getters & setters        
}
```

Serializer

```
    public class PaymentSerializer implements Serializer<Paymnt> {


        public PaymentSerializer(){

        }

        public void close() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public byte[] serialize(String arg0, Paymnt payment) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                oos.writeObject(payment);
                oos.close();
                byte[] b= baos.toByteArray();
                return b;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return new byte[0];
            }

        }

}
```

Appreciate your help.Thank you

Comment: By default, your consumer will start cosuming from the end of topic. Did you try producing after starting the consumer?

Comment: @Treziac yes I ran consumer after producing the records.

Comment: @Treziac whether my custom serializer and deserializer looks fine?I'm posting my serializer code also

Comment: To reiterate @Treziac's question, have you tried using `props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");`?

Comment: @vahid yes it did not help

Comment: Have you tried running console consumer? Is it showing anything?

Comment: @Falan yes it doesn't show anything

Comment: are you sure the topic exists? is auto-create enabled?
and i'm quite confused that ou write that thread is blocking on poll

Comment: Then fix your producer first. Once you see data in console consumer, then continue your test.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and solved the issue by using 1.0.0 kafka installation version. Perhaps you are using a different version of kafka installation ?